# Comparative operation of a variable to an element of a list

Tags: python, comparison

I am a beginner in Python and have just started to learn it. I am just creating a simple code script which should display the name of the candidate who has secured the rank, entered by the user. But when I execute the code it is running the print statement under the else command and doesn't make the comparisons when I enter the number that is a part of the list. Kindly help me with your suggestions.

````
print('Enter the Rank:')
x = input()
if x is list[0]:
    print('Jack has secured First rank')    
elif x is list[1]:
    print('Brown has secured Second rank')   
elif x is list[2]:
    print('Martin has secured Third rank')  
else:
    print('Sorry you have failed')```
````

Comment: Start by forgetting about the `is` operation for now: it is almost never the one you want. It's not just an English-like synonym for `==`.

Answer (score 1):

`is` operator checks whether both the operands refer to the same object or not while `==` compares the values of both the operands.

I guess that you want to compare the values of `x` and `list` members so change the `is` operator you use into `==`:

````
print('Enter the Rank:')
x = input()
if x == list[0]:
    print('Jack has secured First rank')    
elif x == list[1]:
    print('Brown has secured Second rank')   
elif x == list[2]:
    print('Martin has secured Third rank')  
else:
    print('Sorry you have failed')```
````

As a side note, try to avoid naming your variables with built-in names like `list`.